# How to create a document with custom ID in Firebase? Flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

```
updateData() {
  Map<String, dynamic> demoData = {
    "Username": storedUsername,
    "Level": storedLevel,
  };
  //CollectionReference collectionReference =
  Firestore.instance
      .collection('liga_online')
      .document('userID')
      .updateData(demoData);
}



create() {
  
  Map<String, dynamic> demoData = {
    "Username": storedUsername,
    "Level": storedLevel,
  };
  CollectionReference collectionReference =
      Firestore.instance.collection('liga_online');
  collectionReference.add(demoData);          

}

//I could update specific document but I can't create it
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use set instead of update,

```
updateData() async { 
Map<String, dynamic> demoData = { "Username": storedUsername, "Level": storedLevel, }; 
await  Firestore.instance .collection('liga_online') .document('test') .setData(demoData); } //will create a document called "test".
```

Also, you should upgrade your current firestore dependency, Since you are using `document` , now it's `doc`